# How to check maven installed in Drools machine

Tags: maven, drools

I have installed Drools in my machine and we have m2 repository in our linux machine. Does that mean maven installed in my machine.
If  type mvn -v its saying command not found.

I am new to this maven. Kindly help me out

Comment: Drools and Maven are two completely different technologies. If you install one that does not mean the other is installed. The error you have indicated means that the mvn binary is not on your path; if you have installed maven you may have missed the step where you need to put the binary (bin dir) on the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drools is a library. It does not "install". You add it as a dependency to a Java project. If you "installed" something, it's not Drools. Perhaps it's jBPM or some other application which *uses* Drools.

Maven is a toolchain. When you install it, the zip file includes a binary that you need to put on your path. That binary (`mvn`) allows you to run from the commandline.

The two are not related in any way.

If you get an error when trying to run `mvn -v` that the command is not recognized, that means that the Maven binary is not on your path. Find where you installed Maven, locate the 'bin' directory in that installation, and add that bin directory to your Path environment variable.

If you did not install Maven, and therefore don't have an install directory, you probably want to go do that. Don't forget to put the bin directory on your path after installing.

(A less common way of using Maven involves packaging a `mvn.cmd` or `mvn.sh` script with your project itself so that you don't need to have Maven installed globally. If this is what you're doing instead, you need to run the `mvn` command from the same directory as that script.)